Table visual forecast using PowerBI?
Can it possible to display forecasted values in table view separate visual. I have applied forecasting using line chart but i want to display forecasted values in table view is it possible using PowerBI tool?

No Currently it is not possible to show Forecast values in table visual . However, You can use R/Python script to create a column with forecast values and show the same in table visual.
